# Is it possible to have a Java interface that has abstract and full methods?

Tags: java, interface, abstract

If I have an interface that I want developers to implement, but I want them to only override certain methods and have non-abstract methods be left alone. Like below, I want the `getX()` and `getY()` to be overridden, but I want `getXPlusY()` to not be. Do I have to use an abstract class with an interface to accomplish this or something?

```
public interface Summifier {

    public int getX();
    public int getY();

    public int getXPlusY() { 
        return getX() + getY();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just use a single abstract class to implement this, just ensure that any method you don't want subclasses overriding is `final`, eg `public final int getXPlusY()`. This will ensure that subclasses cannot redefine the `getXPlusY()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8, this can be done by [default methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html):

```
public interface Summifier {

    public int getX();
    public int getY();

    // Note the default keyword
    default public int getXPlusY() { 
        return getX() + getY();
    }
}
```

In older versions of Java, you'd have to have an abstract class to implement this functionality.

Comment: This will not prevent `getXPlusY` from being overridden.

Comment: Darn, if my company would only move off of Java 6... this is pretty slick. While having the ability to make the default method final would be nice, this is progress in abstract object programming.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a default method from Java 8: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. In theory an interface cannot have any implementation because it defines a contract and just that.

However in Java 8 they added default methods http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html which look a lot like what you need in here.